# How to run an HTA as another user via VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, hta

I am trying to launch a HTA, via VBS script with my domain account (and have it prompt me for

The script and hta will be in the same directory on a flash drive, so the code has to point to the current directory of the script.

The code below currently launches the hta from the scripts directory, but I am not able to pass a username (eg domain/username) to launch the hta as another user

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName (WScript.ScriptFullName)
If FSO.FileExists(strPath & "\main.HTA") Then
     objShell.ShellExecute "mshta", Chr(34) & strPath & "\main.HTA" & Chr(34), "", "runas", 1
Else
     MsgBox "Error - HTA was not found"
End If
```

How can I save the username (and/or password) as variables and pass it to the runas part of the script to launch the HTA with different user credentials?

EDIT:

Here is the Batch file equivalent of what I am trying to do:

```
runas /user:domain\username "c:\windows\system32\mshta.exe \"\main.hta\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current username you can get with the code below, passwords can't be got by any means I think.

```
Set network = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
currentUser = network.userName
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to prompt the user for a username, save it in a variable, then pass the username to "runas" script (so that I can run the HTA with different user credentials)

This is the batch code for what I am trying to do:





runas /user:domain\username "c:\windows\system32\mshta.exe \"\main.hta\

Comment: Hmm... It seems I didn't understand the question correctly. Unfortenately I'm not familiar with VBScript, so I can't answer this properly. However, I suppose `showModalDialog()` can be used also through VBScript. You could put a couple of inputs there and get values back in the `returnValue` of the dialog...?